# PHP ONE Script to handle ALL requests

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, optimization, refactoring

I just started with PHP development and I've been looking at my company's web server files. The previous programmers have put a single endpoint to handle all requests. For example,

```
www.example.com/webservice.php
```

Using this endpoint, the client will send a myriad of query parameters with an "action" parameter that is mandatory. "action"'s value dictates the function that will be called.

So, webservice.php is a large file with an extremely long if...else statement, which checks $_GET["action"] and calls the respective function in another file (functions.php) together with the related parameters.

My concerns regarding this design is:-

- The performance issue

With almost ~100 else if checks for "action", surely it is not efficient coding right?

- The RESTfulness of the design

Having some knowledge regarding the RESTful philosophy, my approach would be to separate it into components such as

```
www.example.com/module/submodule/action.php
```

Comment: there is no question here

Comment: Mmhmm, and your question is?

Comment: Well.. sorry i did not make it clear.. I just want to know if the current design is bad, if it is bad because the way i say it is (performance). And if my approach is in the right direction

Comment: that would be an off-topic opinion based question:

Comment: I'm doubtful there would be any serious performance issues from 100 "if statements" on a string like that.

Answer (score 1):

Most large PHP applications and MVC frameworks use URL rewriting so even though the URL looks like `www.example.com/user/get/5` it really is all starting at some `index.php` file and perhaps invoking some `routes.php` file when then dispatches the appropriate controller.

It sounds like you are dealing with a legacy application however and yes 100 if else cases is not ideal, but the issue is not having a single entry point, but rather the quality of code that resides in that file.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Didn't know about URL rewriting

Answer (score 1):

The 100 if-then-else could be turned into a `switch`, which might be cleaner.

Another trick is to have 100 functions.  Let's say the actions are 'foo' and 'bar', etc.  The functions could be `Go_foo` and `Go_bar`, etc.  Then some semi-ugly code would go direct to the desired function:

```
$to = @$_GET['action'];
if (! isset($to))  die("action= must be supplied");
$fcn = "Go_$to";
$fcn->();
```

Each function would parse whichever arguments it needs.  (Or you could parse some/all up front.)

As others have said, the performance hit is negligible.  Focus on clarity of code, not speed.

`<opinion>`As for "REST", I find it to be an unnecessarily bloated syntax that provides nothing over old-fashioned arguments.  Even the "versioning" turns out to be useless.  An argument is `/widgit/123` instead of `&widgit=123`; I think `=` is clearer.`